# Logging RequestId in from Lambda@Edge in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda-edge

I am working on a set of Lambda@Edge and trying to setup some audit logging.  When the events end up in CloudWatch, I can see the START and END events are logging a RequestId, which appears to be a UUID.  In the event I receive in the Lambda code, there is a `requestId` in `Records[0].cf.config.requestId`.  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html) says the `requestId` is

> An encrypted string that uniquely identifies a viewer-to-CloudFront
> request. The requestId value also appears in CloudFront access logs as
> x-edge-request-id.

But it doesn't say how it's encrypted.

1. Is this `requestId` in the event the same `RequestId` I am seeing logged from CF in those START/END event logs?
2. How can I get the RequestId such that I can log it w/ my audit logs so we can more easily group the log events together?
3. Is there a reason it's encrypted if it's already logged in CW?
4. Is it bad practice to decrypt that value and log it?